# Sanding vs power washing vs chemical cleaning wooden deck for restoration

Tags: wood, cleaning, deck

There seems to be various methods for cleaning and preparing a wooden deck for restoration.  Some how-to's that I have read strongly advise against power washing.  Some sources suggest a combination of the three methods.

There seems to be pros and cons to each method.
**Can someone provide a guide to help me determine the best method for my deck?**

I realize that the best method may be specific to the type of wood, current condition of the deck and perhaps other factors.  I'm not necessarily looking for an answer specific for my case but would appreciate a more generic answer, possibly in the form of

> [This method] is best for [this type of wood], in [these conditions]
>   and should be avoided for [these conditions]...

The ideal answer would be comprehensive guide that can help DIYers determine which method is best suited for their specific decks.

Comment: What type of wood and existing finish are on the deck, and what is its general condition?

Comment: I believe it's currently painted but am unsure of the type of wood.

Comment: no generic answer. what do you mean by restoration?

Comment: Perhaps restoration is the wrong word.  Refinishing? I would like to remove the paint and reseal the wood to protect it.

Comment: Photographs would be helpful. After removing the paint (are you certain it is paint?) what specific product have you chosen to apply? Size of the deck? Geographic location?

Comment: You have to be careful with a power washer, it can damage the wood if you get the nozzle too close. If the paint / stain is even halfway stuck, it seems like it would be tough to get off. You may want to get the loose stuff off and then put another solid stain on top of it.

Comment: Fine Home Building has an article on this precis topic, covering the entire project.  Saw it in the grocery this afternoon in one of their special pubs as a reprint.  Didn't want to spend the $10.